# How to initialize a class with a primitive in C++(like std::string initialized from const char*)

Tags: c++, oop

What I've been wondering for a while, across many different languages, now in c++, is how do you initialize an object with a primitive? I'm curious about how std::string initializes with a const char* and I want to know if there's a simple way of doing that. Apologies if this question is badly formatted, I've just not found any like this on stackoverflow and this is my first or second question ever. Thanks!

Comment: It just has a constructor that takes a `const char *`.

Comment: Oh really? I didn't know that worked with c++, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can write something like that:

```cpp
std::string s = "hello world!";
```

It's because the constructor of the [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) class takes a `const char *`

> `std::string` is a `std::basic_string<char>`

For example, if you want to instantiate an object of your custom class with a primitive data type, you have just to define a constructor that allow it:

```cpp
class MyCustomClass
{
public:
    MyCustomClass(int a) : m_integer(a) {}
    MyCustomClass(const char* s) : m_integer(std::atoi(s)) {}
    int getValue() const { return m_integer; }

private:
    int m_integer;
};
```

This class allow you to use it like this:

```cpp
MyCustomClass mcc1 = 2;    // Use MyCustomClass(int a)
MyCustomClass mcc2 = "12"; // Use MyCustomClass(const char* s)

// Will print : 2
std::cout << mcc1.getValue() << std::endl;
// Will print : 12
std::cout << mcc2.getValue() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Technically, the working of `std::string` is more complicated than that.  In fact, `std::string` is not actually defined as a class - it is a type alias for a specialisation of a templated class.    And the constructor of that templated class - which causes `std::string` to accept a `const char *` when being constructed - accepts two arguments.

Comment: @Peter, Yes great precision, but for simplify the understanding, I write this example. I add some little precisions.

Comment: @thibsc - Don't worry, I understood that.   In principle, your answer is correct, and I've upvoted accordingly.   It's just that, for the particular case of `std::string`, what you say is relevant for users of `std::string`, but the implementation is somewhat more complicated (for various reasons) than you describe.